# Performance and optimization codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variable-assignment

I wonder which of these two forms is more efficient in Codeigniter.
In option 1 the data array is passed to all views.
In Option 2 each data array has a different name doing to not forget all the info
to each view.
I want to assume that Option 2 is correct, I mean rename each array, not spend
unnecessary information to each view.
Am I correct? Codeigniter or not it matter?
Thanks for reading the post
regards

OPTION 1

```
public function alguna_funcion(){


       $data['datos1'] = $this->modelo->function1();
       $data['widget1'] = $this->load->view('widget1',$data,TRUE);
       $data['datos2'] = $this->modelo->function2();
       $data['widget2'] = $this->load->view('widget2',$data,TRUE);
       $data['datos3'] = $this->modelo->function3();
       $data['widget3'] = $this->load->view('widget3',$data,TRUE);
       $data['datos4'] = $this->modelo->function4();
       $data['widget4'] = $this->load->view('widget4',$data,TRUE);

       $this->load->view('home_view',$data);


   }
```

OPTION 2

```
public function alguna_funcion(){


       $data1['datos1'] = $this->modelo->function1();
       $data['widget1'] = $this->load->view('widget1',$data1,TRUE);
       $data2['datos2'] = $this->modelo->function2();
       $data['widget2'] = $this->load->view('widget2',$data2,TRUE);
       $data3['datos3'] = $this->modelo->function3();
       $data['widget3'] = $this->load->view('widget3',$data3,TRUE);
       $data4['datos4'] = $this->modelo->function4();
       $data['widget4'] = $this->load->view('widget4',$data4,TRUE);

       $this->load->view('home_view',$data);


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it like this

```
public function alguna_funcion()
{
    $data['datos'] = $this->modelo->function1();
    $data['widget1'] = $this->load->view('widget1',$data,TRUE);
    unset($data['datos']);

    $data['datos'] = $this->modelo->function2();
    $data['widget2'] = $this->load->view('widget2',$data,TRUE);
    unset($data['datos']);

    $data['datos'] = $this->modelo->function3();
    $data['widget3'] = $this->load->view('widget3',$data,TRUE);
    unset($data['datos']);

    $data['datos'] = $this->modelo->function4();
    $data['widget4'] = $this->load->view('widget4',$data,TRUE);
    unset($data['datos']);

    // Now you have only widgets pass them to view
    $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not fault of CodeIgniter. As long as data_i are all the same, accessing their elements can be done either in one of the two ways as indicated and then the latter case seems redundant.-

Comment: In option 1 the information travels for all views, and there are views that do not require all the information in the array data but only a part.
My question is, all that information traveling view it is a waste of resources? becomes heavier load of the page? or not?

Comment: Of course the more objects to be constructed, the more fragments to be created. Either Web or Desktop applications do need access to physical RAM or resources. This is why you can observe live changes of memory blocks used by i.e some web's animated objects. Slow or fast loading of a page depends on many factors (bandwidth, page size, local as well as remote resources handling, UI interaction etc).
Since PHP and Javascript allow you to do something like 
`for(int i=0;i<n;i++) { obj="string_"+i; }`

you can do the same using `echo $i` wrapped up in quotes to make referenced keys as you wish.

Comment: Sorry but I do not speak English and did not quite understand the translation of his answer.
Which ultimately is the most efficient? option1 or option2?

Comment: Ok please define "efficient".

Comment: For example: if I have a view that you only need to send the text "hello", but instead I send an array with 2000 elements, and one of them is "hello".
In that case the view is getting much unnecessary information, since you need only "hello".
I think this may reduce site performance, as it uses more memory unnecessarily.
This is the case of Option 1, wherein the data array, containing all the information, is traveling to all views.
My question is, all those who are receiving unnecessary information views, causes low performance?
Efficient: Server efficient

Comment: OK, yes and no. 'Yes' is in case the option 1's data object which is passed to the view in each scenario is not fully used; only the initialized array element, in particular for example - data['datos1'] is processed in  `$this->load->view('widget1',$data,TRUE)`. And 'No' is applied in case many elements will be used. You also mention in your comment that your array object may be very large in size, which also means other elements of the array itself may be analyzed or used in the *widget* view the object is being passed to.To resolve this, you can just include the objects needed for each view.